# Регулярное выражение для поиска мобильного телефона в тексте

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, node.js, ecmascript-6

Подскажите регулярное выражение для поиска номера мобильного телефона в тексте.

Номера телефонов вводятся разными пользователями и в совершенно непредсказуемом формате, например могут участвовать -+()_ пробелы и еще не известно на что хватит фантазии.

Примеры телефонов:

8 900 000-00-00

+7 (900) 000 00-00

+7 9001112233

89001112233

8(900) 111-2233

и т.д

Comment: Интересует поиск именно в тексте, то есть может быть больше одного номера? Или есть строчка, где только номер телефона?

Comment: @diraria может быть больше одного номера

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
/(?:\+|\d)[\d\-\(\) ]{9,}\d/g
```

- Начинается с: "+" или цифры
- Потом может содержать: цифры, "-", "(", ")", пробел. Повторяющиеся 9 и больше раз
- Заканчивается цифрой

https://regex101.com/r/poJz8C/5

Answer (score 4):

Думаю, примерно так:

```
/(\+7|8)[- _]*\(?[- _]*(\d{3}[- _]*\)?([- _]*\d){7}|\d\d[- _]*\d\d[- _]*\)?([- _]*\d){6})/g
```

```js
console.log(
"8 900 000-00-00\
+7 (900) 000 00-00\
+7 9001112233\
89001112233\
8(900) 111-2233\
8 (1234) 12 12 12\
8 (12-34) 12 12 12\
8  ( 123 )  412 12 12".match(
/(\+7|8)[- _]*\(?[- _]*(\d{3}[- _]*\)?([- _]*\d){7}|\d\d[- _]*\d\d[- _]*\)?([- _]*\d){6})/g
))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

Comment: код страны может начинаться не только с 7 или 8, вроде там [1-9]

Comment: И 7 могут указать без +

Comment: @MedvedevDev, если телефон российский, то только +7 или 8. 7 без плюса - это какая-то муть, но если автор захочет, один вопросик поставить догадается.

Comment: судя по формулировке вопроса, рассчитывать на "немутность" указания номера не приходится ))))

Answer (score 2):

`/(?:\+|\d)[\d\-\(\) ]{9,}\d/g` так лучше

Answer (score 0):

Небольшая доработка

```
(?<=^|\s|>|\;|\:|\))(?:\+|7|8|9|\()[\d\-\(\) ]{8,}\d
```

Первая группа смотрит вперед, но не попадает в выборку. Нужно, чтобы не срабатывало на параметры в ссылках и подобный мусор.

Второе - с чего начинается номер.

У меня это +, 7, 8, 9 (для сотовых) и с открывающейся скобки - иногда номер пишут начиная с кода города, опуская +7.

Answer (score -1):

```
[0-9|\ |\-|\(|\)|\+]{10,17}[0-9|\ |\-|\(|\)]
```

Answer (score -1):

Простой и понятный вариант можете сами подобрать здесь https://regex101.com/
или вот такой:
`/(^[7|8]{0,1}\d{10}$)|(^\+7{1}\d{10}$)/` где
`^` - это начало строки.
`$` - это конец строки.
`[7|8]{0,1}` - 7 или 8 могут быть 1 раз или 0 раз.
`\d{10}` - числа должны повторяться 10 раз.
`|` - знак или.
`(^\+7{1}\d{10}$)` - здесь аналогично

Comment: `{0,1}` - вы это серьёзно? Почитайте про уточняющие квантификаторы.